# Bootstrap navigation in carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Lately I have been trying to get in Bootstrap and I know how CSS works most of the times, however (because I am a "typical lazy programmer", a saying by an old teacher of mine) I wonder if it is possible in Bootstrap to combine the following options: [Bootstrap Carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/) with [Bootstrap static top navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/)? I tried toying with the bootstrap classes within my HTML page (containing the carousel code) but it always seems to appear as the "default" navigation:

`<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">`

to

`<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">`

(in following HTML: http://pastebin.com/mqDhi1Vu I am using MVC so my [base view](http://pastebin.com/KuiRCw1K) contains the necessary code to link stylesheet(s))

(Yeah I actually want it to get the navbar-static-top class, but it still shows like default)

Should I make custom CSS for this or is it possible to make this happen with just plain Bootstrap classes?

**Edit:** I added my base view to the question, but it is not worth mentioning that navigation should be in there instead, I am aware of that, but it has nothing to do with my question afaik for now.

Maybe my question would be more specific/clear if you would read it like this: Is it possible to show the carousel below the navigation instead of the navigation appearing inside the carousel?

Comment: How did you try? Please give us your sample html, css.

Comment: For CSS I'm using Bootstrap only. I am not using custom CSS (yet). The only HTML I am using is the HTML used for the Bootstrap Carousel. Take a look at my question which I have edited to see what tag I was trying to refer to.

Comment: There is no way for anyone to see what you're seeing, or what the problem is. Try putting your example into JsFiddle.net

Comment: @Lee Like I said, I just want the navigation bar to be on top of the browser window and disappear when scrolling down: https://jsfiddle.net/eoutn0r0/
I am sorry if it's hard for you to understand.

Comment: Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cy1jagry/

Comment: I have got to say I got it to work by extracting only the carousel (tag or element) HTML and only the navigation (tag or element) HTML and put both of them in my own custom HTML after a bit of fiddling. Not sure if it's entirely as for how Bootstrap was intended, but it works now.

Comment: I think it would probably be hard for anyone to understand, or else you'd have some responses! From reading your question again.. I still cannot see how that's what you're trying to do. But glad you got it to work. You could easily juse the jQuery plugin StickyTabs to change the class of the bar as you scroll past it. Then just set CSS rules to change it's position/styling.

Comment: And yes I think natively, they're not nested. It depends on how you code it, that's why I wanted to see your markup. It sounds like you nested your navbar inside the carousel div. Or you needed a clearfix div somewhere to break them up.